# How Could I Delete Downloaded Default Wallpapers?

Tags: macos

I've downloaded some of the optional wallpapers in the settings panel and I can't find the option to delete them. They're 100MB HEIC files so I'd rather them not sit on my drive being unused. How could I delete them? I've downloaded the Big Sur and Catalina wallpapers.

[image: Screenshot of my Desktop & Screen Saver page, with the Big Sur and Catalina wallpapers downloaded]

Comment: If you know the sizes, I assume you’ve located the files. Can you simply delete them or are they protected?

Comment: i just confirmed - it is protected, and not permitted to delete even using `sudo rm`

Answer (score -1):

Double-click on the folder `Desktop Pictures` under Apple in the left-pane of the above shown image, it will open the folder location in Finder.

Voila! Select and `⌘ ⌫`

Comment: This opens `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures` for me, can't delete anything there.